# Incorrect NSStringEncoding - compatiblity (sic) mapping

Tags: cocoa, debugging, nsstringencoding

I'm using Xcode 4.6 with a Cocoa project, using 10.8 SDK, deploying for 10.6.

Using LLVM 4.2.

My log file is being littered with the following error:

```
Incorrect NSStringEncoding value 0x0000 detected. Assuming NSASCIIStringEncoding. Will stop this compatiblity mapping behavior in the near future.
```

I am trying to narrow down the culprit, and so far have been unable to find any encoding: calls that use 0, nil, or NULL.

**Question:** how do I determine where in the code this message is being generated?  Is there a way to break on this message, in the Debugger?

(I have searched for all usage of encoding: in my own code.)

Thanks.

Comment: Try putting a breakpoint on `NSLog()` and `NSLogv()`.

Comment: Thank you.  For completion, I used this in the debug console: 

(lldb) breakpoint set -n NSLog